# Why does my NavigationView bounce back to its initial view?

Tags: swift, swiftui, navigation

I'm trying to create a programmatically-driven view navigation with SwiftUI 2 with an `environmentObject` that is used to store the `selection` of the current view in a NavigationView.

I'm aware the below code navigation could simply work with only navigation links directly but my actual code is more complex and views will have to be navigated based on receiving a network response among possibly other mechanisms and I want to create a clear and unified navigation logic for this so I'm trying to use the `currentView` property in the environment object.

**ContentView**:

```
import SwiftUI

enum NavigationViewTarget: String {
    case ContentView
    case RegistrationView
    case LoginView
    case LandingView
}

final class GlobalViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var currentView: NavigationViewTarget? = .ContentView
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = GlobalViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader {
            screen in
            
            NavigationView {
                ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        HStack {
                            NavigationLink(destination: RegistrationView(), tag: .RegistrationView, selection: $viewModel.currentView) { EmptyView() }.hidden()
                            NavigationLink(destination: LoginView(), tag: .LoginView, selection: $viewModel.currentView) { EmptyView() }.hidden()
                            Button(action: { viewModel.currentView = .RegistrationView }) {
                                Text("Register")
                            }
                            Button(action: { viewModel.currentView = .LoginView }) {
                                Text("Login")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
            }
        }
        .environmentObject(viewModel)
    }
}
```

**RegistrationView**:

```
import SwiftUI

struct RegistrationView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: GlobalViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader {
            screen in
            
            ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    HStack {
                        NavigationLink(destination: LandingView(), tag: .LandingView, selection: $viewModel.currentView) { EmptyView() }.hidden()

                        Button(action: { viewModel.currentView = .LandingView }) {
                            Text("Submit")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**LandingView**:

```
struct LandingView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: GlobalViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Landing View")
    }
}
```

**LoginView**:

import SwiftUI

```
struct LoginView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: GlobalViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Login View")
    }
}
```

The app navigates to `RegistrationView` and when tapping the Submit button in it it navigates to `LandingView` but then automatically bounces back to `ContentView`. Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: The landing view is subview of registering view. So when you set current view to landing it display but at the same time in content view the visibility of subview have changed. So registering view is no more visible (so it’s subviews) . Landing view should ve subview of contents view or depends on another variable.

Comment: @PtitXav I see now. This is still very confusing in SwiftUI. Any idea how I need to change it so the LandingView is used as a sub view of ContentView but opened from RegistrationView?

Comment: You should use a state var in registration view and not modify environment var.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Though it nullified my idea to keep the navigation state nicely confined in one place.

Comment: It depends on how you plan doing all your navigation. You could use the model view if you put NavigationLink(.Landing) in ContentView : in this case when doin Submit in registration you will be in a sub view of ContentView. Landing view then only return to ContentView not registerView.